# How to handle duplicates in my PATH variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, path

I recently added this line to my `.bashrc` file so that I could use the java compiler `javac` from the command line (using MobaXTerm if that makes a difference)

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin"
```

But I'm seeing multiple duplicates in my `$PATH` variable (note that the newlines were only added for readability)

```
/bin:
/drives/c/Users/Justin/DOCUME~1/MobaXterm/slash/bin:
/drives/c/WINDOWS:
/drives/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:
/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:
/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm adding to my `$PATH`?

Comment: Take a look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command

Comment: Did you mean to say `export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin"`?

Comment: Unless you are repeatedly sourcing your bashrc, then that path should be set once, unless it is being set somewhere else as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If PATH is manipulated by different scripts that are called by `.bashrc`, this is usually the result.

While duplicates in PATH aren't a major problem, there are two approaches to keeping PATH free of them:

1. Check if a dir already exists in PATH before adding
2. Dedupe PATH as the last step in your `.bashrc`

**Check before adding**

```
javabin="/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin"
if ! [[ $PATH =~ "$javabin" ]]; then
  PATH="$PATH:$javabin"
fi
```

or write a function:

```
add_to_path() {
    local dir re

    for dir; do
        re="(^$dir:|:$dir:|:$dir$)"
        if ! [[ $PATH =~ $re ]]; then
            PATH="$PATH:$dir"
        fi
    done
}

add_to_path "/cygdrive/c/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin"
```

**Dedupe** (the best method I found on SO)

```
PATH="$(perl -e 'print join(":", grep { not $seen{$_}++ } split(/:/, $ENV{PATH}))')"
```

---

See also on Unix & Linux / SuperUser StackExchange:

- [PATH is filled with duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/449636/path-is-filled-with-duplicates)
- [Remove duplicate $PATH entries with awk command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149054/201820)
- [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Comment: Will `<<<` not put an extra newline at the end of the last path?

Comment: Good point, @123.  I replaced the awk solution with something more elegant I found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149054/201820

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I have a bash alias that sources my `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called pathmunge defined in /etc/profile:

```
pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}
```

Unfortunately, it is also unset at the end of the file.  However, just delete the unset line, and you can use it in .bashrc file.

Comment: There is no `pathmunge` function in `/etc/profile` on my system, and I don't recommend modifying system files like that. It would be better to define `pathmunge` in your own `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's on Redhat, top of the file literally says `It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
 are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
 /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
 will prevent the need for merging in future updates.`

Comment: @123: Sure, but it's even better to make custom shell scripts in your home directory. Mucking around in `/etc/profile.d` makes sense only if you want to make things available to all users on the system. (A lot of systems these days only have one user, but it's still a useful distinction.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I wasn't arguing, I was agreeing that `/etc/profile` shouldn't be changed. I quoted the whole comment but the relevant part was `It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you are doing.`